# Checking for null/empty arrays in a Unity c# script

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I have a Unity game using WebGL and c#.

I am running Unity 2020.2.6f1, from what I understand is using c# 7.3

I currently check for null or empty arrays like this:

```
ObjectType[] myObjectTypeList = FindObjectsOfType<ObjectType>();

if(myObjectTypeList != null && myObjectTypeList.Length > 0)
{
    ...
}
```

But I read that in c# 7+ you can shorten to this:

```
if(!(myObjectTypeList?.Length != 0))
{
    ...
}
```

Is this something I can do in a Unity c# script when I am using `FindObjectsOfType`?

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In <s>C#7</s> **C# 8.0** you can use the `is` operator and, your `if` statement could be

```cs
if (myObjectTypeList is {Length: > 0}){
    // [...]
}
```

which is equal to

```cs
if (myObjectTypeList != null && myObjectTypeList.Length > 0){
    // [...]
}
```

---

## Edit

This answer is wrong.

According to [Microsoft's Documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/operators/patterns#property-pattern):

> Beginning with C# 8.0, you use a property pattern to match an expression's properties or fields against nested patterns [...]

This feature works only from c#8.0 and later. That said, this answer will still work, since [Unity Version 2020.2 uses Roslyn Compiler with C# 8.0 Language Support](https://docs.unity3d.com/2020.2/Documentation/Manual/CSharpCompiler.html).

Comment: Oh I see, so that notation checks for not null and length together?

Comment: Exactly. But, as per my edit, my answer is wrong.

Comment: Funnily enough, it seems like my answer will still work, as, [your Unity Version indicates that it uses C# 8.0](https://docs.unity3d.com/2020.2/Documentation/Manual/CSharpCompiler.html)

Comment: Additional information that might also be usefull about `is` operator:

This operator can do multiple things at the same time. Want to typecheck, cast, validate a member value and use an object at the same time? for:

`object myObjectTypeListAsObject`

could work like 

`if (myObjectTypeListAsObject is ObjectType[] {Length: > 0} myObjectTypeList) {  /*stuff with myObjectTypeList*/ }`

Answer (score 2):

The `?.` is called the `Null Conditional Operator`. `a?.b` will resolve to `b`, unless `a` is `null`, in which case it resolves to `null`. This operator  was actually new since C# 6.0.

Comment: Ok so I need to check and make sure the array is both not null and also not empty so I don't get null reference errors in Unity. would that still work?  thanks!

Comment: @SkyeBoniwell - Yes

Answer (score 2):

If you can live with the warnings you will get about calling an extension method on a null, this should work:

```
public static class Extensions
{
    public static bool NotNullHasItems<T> (this IEnumerable<T> collection)
    {
        if (collection == null)
        {
            return false;
        }
        return collection.Any();
    }
}
```

To test this, I used:

```
List<string> stuff = null;
var shouldBeFalse = stuff.NotNullHasItems();
stuff = new List<string>();
var shouldAlsoBeFalse = stuff.NotNullHasItems();
stuff.Add("test");
var shouldBeTrue = stuff.NotNullHasItems();
```

and both `shouldBeFalse` and `shouldAlsoBeFalse` ended up `false` while `shouldBeTrue` was true.

You may want a better name (perhaps reverse the logic and name it `IsNullOrEmpty` to match `string.IsNullOrEmpty`)